# Error 554 when using Amazon SES as Firebase custom SMTP mail server

Tags: firebase, smtp, amazon-ses

i'm migrating our current custom SMTP mail server for Firebase Authentication mails to Amazon SES. I generated new SMTP credentials and updated the Firebase SMTP settings:
[image: Firebase SMTP Settings]

But when i try to send a password reset mail, i continuously receive this error in the sender's inbox: `554 Transaction failed: Missing final '@domain'`.

The same SES SMTP credentials work fine (= emails being sent), when i use them (base64 encoded) in a local CLI script (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html) or on https://www.smtper.net/.

Additional information:

- inspired by the error message, i tried to add my maildomain to the SMTP user's name (`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO@mydomain.net`) but received the error `535 Authentication Credentials Invalid`
- i did not use the account's credentials (as mentioned in most topics), but the SMTP user's credentials
- as mentioned in other related topics, i also tried to URL encode the password with no avail (it contains a `/`). Same for base64 encoding the password
- the custom domain and the sender's address are verified in SES
- i have configured SPF and DKIM for the custom mail domain (also verified)

If i missed any further information, please let me know, thanks in advance.